# Enter cyrillic letters on German keybord

Tags: cyrillic, german, keyboard

I am writing a lecture text which has some short cyrillic parts. 
So far, I am only able to enter cyrillic letters in my *.tex file when I copy and paste them from another document (like MSWord). How do I enter cyrillic text on a German keyboard? Is there something like a correspondence list?  
Thanks in advance for any answer  
Angelika

Comment: Typing Cyrillic directly into the .tex source is probably OS specific, and not within the topics covered by this site.  But if it's only some short Cyrillic parts, you could define some commands `\newcommand{\Be}{Б}` (or find out if some package defines those commands for you).  You wouldn't be able to directly type Cyrillic, but you would be able to have it appear in the output.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a cyrillic keyboard in the operating system but simpler for small sections is to use an online keyboard (eg google suggested https://www.lexilogos.com/keyboard/russian.htm) which allows you to type cyrillic by using the on screen buttons or the transliteration from latin script as shown, then simply past the text into your document.

[image]